# Force a canvas to use available space in a flex column

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a full size page, containing a top toolbar, and below, a  container with 2 columns:

- a right column
- a left column containing a canvas (centered horizontally and vertically in this column), which has its own coordinates system (typically 4000 x 3000) and should preserve this aspect ratio. This canvas has a "+" button layered on it. (In my real code, there are several canvas for multiple layers, and multiple buttons, but not important here)

[image]

Here it *nearly* works, but I can't  make the canvas occupy the full available space in the left column.

With all methods that I tried (`max-width: 100%`, `max-height: 100%`), either it fails when we zoom in / out in the browser (70% 80% ... 150 %), or it fails because the method used prevents the button to stay on top of the canvas, at its right corner.

**TL;DR: how to make this canvas take all available space in the left column, keeping its aspect ratio, keeping the layered buttons, without overflow?**

Note: I'm looking for a CSS solution, the JS is not for the positioning, but only the drawing.

```js
ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"; ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00"; ctx.fillRect(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF"; ctx.fillRect(2000, 2000, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"; ctx.fillRect(3000, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.toolbar {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 5em;
}

.container {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background-color: magenta;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right {
  background-color: salmon;
  flex: 0 0 10em;
}

.canvas-wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="toolbar">
    TOOLBAR OF HEIGHT 5 EM
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="canvas-wrapper">
        <canvas width="4000" height="3000"></canvas>
        <div class="button">+</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      RIGHT OF WIDTH 10 EM
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: you have to open the snippet in "Full page" to see the browser zoom in / zoom out feature (CTRL + , CTRL -).

Comment: Did you not find the answer on the question on which you placed the bounty?

Comment: @SalmanA No, because the solutions there, did not allow to keep a wrapper of the exact size of the canvas, thus it's impossible to put the buttons on the top right corner of the canvas. So I simplified the question, with a better and different reproducible example (including toolbar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change some alignments, `width`s, `height`s, `flex-grow`s and add an HTML wrapper (i.e., `<div class="canvas-wrapper-inner">`).

See the snippet below.

```js
ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
ctx.fillRect(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
ctx.fillRect(2000, 2000, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(3000, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.toolbar {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 5em;
}

.container {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background-color: magenta;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right {
  background-color: salmon;
  flex: 0 0 10em;
}

.canvas-wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1; /* Added */
  align-self: stretch; /* Added */
  align-items: center; /* Added */
  justify-content: center; /* Added */
}

canvas {
  width: 100%; /* Added */
  flex-grow: 1; /* Added */
  object-fit: contain; /* Added */
  max-height: calc(100vh - 5em); /* Added */
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

/* Added */
.canvas-wrapper-inner {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="toolbar">
    TOOLBAR OF HEIGHT 5 EM
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="canvas-wrapper">
        <div class="canvas-wrapper-inner">
          <canvas width="4000" height="3000"></canvas>
          <div class="button">+</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      RIGHT OF WIDTH 10 EM
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It nearly works, but problem: https://imgur.com/1RHGHI6, here the canvas should take much more height, and keep the 4000/3000 aspect ratio. Also the "+" yellow button should always stay on top of the black square (top right corner of the canvas).

Comment: It should be like this @RokBenko: https://imgur.com/YyZe9l3

Comment: Thanks but when you click on "Full page" in the snippet, it doesn't work @RokBenko, do you see it too?

Comment: By playing with your answer @RokBenko I finally got this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76218640/1422096, do you confirm it works for you too? (Full credit to you, I'll mark your answer as accepted)

Comment: @Basj Yes, I can confirm it works on my side too.

Answer (score 1):

There's a handy unit size called cqmin which is the lowest size of the inline or block sizes. Set container wrapper as a container of type size so the content responds to both block and inline dimesions then set the width of the canvas to 100cqmin. Use aspect-ratio to maintain the, er, aspect ratio.  See example below. I've put a codepen of it [here](https://codepen.io/adamuk73/pen/eYPrOPZ?editors=1100) too.

```js
ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"; ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00"; ctx.fillRect(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF"; ctx.fillRect(2000, 2000, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"; ctx.fillRect(3000, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.toolbar {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 5em;
}

.container {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  container-type: size;
  background-color: magenta;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right {
  background-color: salmon;
  flex: 0 0 10em;
}

.canvas-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100cqmin;
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 4/3;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="toolbar">
    TOOLBAR OF HEIGHT 5 EM
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="canvas-wrapper">
        <canvas width="4000" height="3000"></canvas>
        <div class="button">+</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      RIGHT OF WIDTH 10 EM
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but here it doesn't work: https://imgur.com/w9oJM8q. Any idea why it fails?

Comment: It's because I'm a dumbass and forgot to copy the javascript from your example to the code editor. Urgh. It should be visible now.

Comment: Haha, yes it helps @Adam (I found the same thing in the meantime :)), but still, the plus button is not on the top right corner of the canvas, (it should be there), instead here it's on top right corner *of the right column*. Any idea for this?

Comment: I didn't spot that. I've added the CSS for the button and I've also set the container type on the .left element. I've then sized the canvas-wrapper element as 100cqmin and then used positon: relative to create a new containing block to position the plus button on your canvas. Should work now.

Comment: This doesn't work at larger screen sizes. I'll remove this if that's okay @Basj?

Comment: Please keep it @Adam, it might still be useful, maybe you can edit to mention the corner cases in which it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The `canvas-wrapper` needs to have same size and position as the canvas, but the size and position of the canvas is based on its grand parent. A simple solution is to copy the canvas dimensions as `aspect-ratio` to its parent:

```js
ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
ctx.fillRect(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
ctx.fillRect(2000, 2000, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(3000, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.toolbar {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 5em;
}

.container {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* wrapper for two column layout */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
  background-color: magenta;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* reference element for size and position */
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  background-color: salmon;
  flex: 0 0 10em;
  align-self: center;
}

.canvas-wrapper {
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  background-color: cyan;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="toolbar">
    TOOLBAR OF HEIGHT 5 EM
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="canvas-wrapper" style="aspect-ratio: 4000 / 3000;">
        <canvas width="4000" height="3000"></canvas>
        <div class="button">+</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      RIGHT OF WIDTH 10 EM
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @SalmanA but in your example the toolbar is hidden, whereas it should not. Would you have an idea?

Comment: I've given it one more try. Unfortunately there isn't anything I could do about the `+` button

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer based on RokBenko's answer which seems to work, without the secondary wrapper and the secondary flex:

```js
ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
ctx.fillRect(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
ctx.fillRect(2000, 2000, 1000, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(3000, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.toolbar {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 5em;
}

.container {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background-color: magenta;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right {
  background-color: salmon;
  flex: 0 0 10em;
}

.canvas-wrapper {
  background-color: #aaa;
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 5em);
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="toolbar">
    TOOLBAR OF HEIGHT 5 EM
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="canvas-wrapper">
        <canvas width="4000" height="3000"></canvas>
        <div class="button">+</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      RIGHT OF WIDTH 10 EM
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```